# Why can't I assign to part of my Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, join, pandas, dataframe

I'm confused why the following `pandas` does not successfully assign the last two values of column A to the first two entries of column B:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 'B': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]})
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame({'C': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']}))
df['B2'] = df.B.shift(2)
df[:2].B2 = list(df[-2:].A)
```

What's perplexing to me is that in an (apparently) equivalent "real" application, it does appear to work ([and to generate some strange behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22458039/656912)).

Why does the final assignment fail to change the values of the two entries in the dataframe?

Answer (score 5):

It *can* work and that's why its insidious, see here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Generally with multi-dtyped frames it depends on the construction of *when* it would work (e.g. if you create it all at once, I think it will always work). Since you are creating it *after* (via join) it is dependent on the underlying numpy view creation mechanisms.

don't ever ever ever assign like that, use `loc`

```
df.loc[:2,'B2'] = ....
```

Comment: It seemed a bit too "clever" to be wise! Could the fact that it *did* work in the [linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22458039/656912) account for the (to me) odd alignment behavior there?

Comment: seems likely; the data may or may not be correctly assigned.